# SQL Server 2012 Date Change

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, powerpivot

I am attempting to `convert` the `DATETIME` Column titled `CREAT_DTTM` to a simple "1/1/2014" format.

I have looked at `CAST`, `CONVERT` and `FORMAT` functions but i just can't get it to work.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated! I am running SQL Server 2012

Some sample data

```
CREAT_DTTM
------------------------    
2014-01-01 00:33:58.000    
2014-01-01 00:33:58.000    
2014-01-01 07:40:01.000    
2014-01-01 09:50:27.000    
2014-01-01 10:40:04.000    
2014-01-01 10:40:04.000
```

By convert I mean: This data is being pulled from another table by a stored proc our developer created. It is sales data that shows when an order has been entered into the system. I created a powerpivot data slicer in Excel that is linked to this table but they do not like the format the date is displayed in. So I was attempting to convert it from the aforementioned format to one more acceptable by the stakeholders.  Only thing is that I do not have ample experience in writing queries

Comment: What do you mean by "convert"? What are you doing with the dates that requires the conversion?

Comment: Welcome on SO. Could you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: By convert i mean:  This data is being pulled from another table by a stored proc our developer created.  It is sales data that shows when an order has been entered into the system.  I created a powerpivot data slicer in excel that is linked to this table but they do not like the format the date is displayed in.  So i was attempting to convert it from the aforementioned format to one more acceptable by the stakeholders.  Only thing is that i do not have ample experience in writing queries..pretty much a newbie

Comment: @user3896424 The reason I asked is that converting it to display in another format still keeps the underlying value the same, do you just want to display it in a different format to the user? If so, do that in the presentation layer not in the database.

Comment: This should be done in Excel. Format your cells appropriately.

Comment: I have not updated our stored proc yet.. i just played with a query on the data.. but the suggestion to just format it in excel made me realize that i can reformat it in the powerpivot table window.. so the data slicer will pull the format i need.  Thanks for the help.. i definitely learned a few things from you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following.

```
select convert(varchar(10), creat_dttm, 101)
from yourTable
```

Comment: Wow...not sure why somebody downvoted this. This is exactly how I would do it.

Comment: Probably because this will convert a date to a date.

Comment: Fixed. Oversight on my part.

Comment: Thank you to everyone for the help.. greatly appreciated.. and the above worked to get it into an acceptable format.. once again... i thank each and everyone of you for the help and consideration!!

Comment: Just remember that doing it this way means the client (i.e. Excel) doesn't know it's a date any more and cannot perform things like sorting and puts an unnecessary load on the database if there's lots of date to convert.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the format of the dates in a PowerPivot table through the PowerPivot Window. The advantage here is that you do not need to do any modification of your stored procedure and your datatype is still a date when it comes into your pivot table.

Open your `PowerPivot Window` again
[image]

Select your data column, Select Fromat from the Formatting section on the Home tab.
[image]

Comment: exactly what i did.. that worked and i learned the accurate way to CAST .. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that CAST will do the job nicely for you, 
e.g.

```
select cast(creat_dttm as date)
from theTable
```

Comment: That will have dashes, the OP clearly states the format they want is with slashes.

Comment: @SeanLange: this converts the `DATETIME` to a `DATE` - neither of the two have any *format* associated with them in SQL Server - they're 8 and 3 bytes of binary data respectively. The dashes or slashes only occur when you're doing a **string representation** of those dates (or datetimes)

Comment: I understand the code and difference between datatypes. The OP wants a string representation and they clearly stated slashes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select convert(varchar(15), creat_dttm, 101) from tblTableName
```